# Having difficulties understanding c++ program, shift , &

Tags: c++, shift

In my machine language class we have to translate c++ into mips, the problem is that I do not know much c++, just basic stuff so I am having trouble understating this function:

```
void IPtoDD(int arg0, char *arg1)
{
  int temp, numChar, shift = 24;

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    temp = arg0 >> shift;
    temp = temp & 0x000000ff;
    numChar = byteToDec(temp,arg1);
    arg1 += numChar;
    *arg1++ = '.';
    shift -= 8;
  }
```

In particular

```
    temp = arg0 >> shift;
    temp = temp & 0x000000ff;
```

Comment: Why not trace this code step by step in debugger and see what is happening? You'll learn more figuring it yourself rather than somebody describing it for you.

Comment: See [bitwise right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators) and [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: As a hint: I'd guess for machine language there should be single instructions available that exactly do this for each of these operations.

Answer (score 2):

The `>>` operator is a "shift right operator."  It will shift the binary representation of the value on the left by x bits right, where x is the number on the right.  What does this look like?  Here are some examples:

```
decimal: 128                   >> 1 == 64
binary:  0b0000 0000 1000 0000 >> 1 == 0b0000 0000 0100 0000

decimal: 64                    >> 1 == 32
binary:  0b0000 0000 0100 0000 >> 1 == 0b0000 0000 0010 0000
```

Notice how the 1 in the big binary numbers gets shifted right by 1.  In your code, you are shifting `arg0` by `shift`, where `arg0` is some input and `shift` is 24, 16, 8, then 0 since you're looping.  This means the first loop through, you shift `arg0` down by 24 bits, then store it into temp.

The second statement is a bitwise AND which compares each bit of the left-hand side with each respective bit of the right hand.  If both bits are 1, the resulting bit in the same position is 1, otherwise it is 0.  Here are some examples:

```
decimal: 7      & 15     == 7
binary:  0b0111 & 0b1111 == 0b0111

decimal: 5      & 12     == 4
binary:  0b0101 & 0b1100 == 0b0100
```

In your expressions, the AND is done with a right hand side value of `0x000000FF` which is the hexadecimal equivalent of 255, in decimal.

What your two statements of interest are doing, is extracting each "byte" or "8-bit chunk" from the input `arg0`:

```
temp = arg0 >> shift;
temp = temp & 0x000000ff;

Input:  arg0 = 0x12345678, shift = 24
Output: temp = 0x12

Input:  arg0 = 0x12345678, shift = 0
Output: temp = 0x78
```

**ADDENDUM ABOUT SHIFT RIGHT:**

You are shifting a *signed* integer by right here, but fortunately you are masking the bits off with the following AND mask.  For completeness sake, shift right on a signed integer can do one of two things (assuming 16-bit numbers here, results would be different for 32-bit or 64-bit numbers):

Arithmetic Shift Right:

```
decimal: -128                  >> 1 == -64
binary:  0b1111 1111 1000 0000 >> 1 == 0b1111 1111 1100 0000
```

Logical Shift Right:

```
decimal: -128                  >> 1 == 32704
binary:  0b1111 1111 1000 0000 >> 1 == 0b0111 1111 1100 0000
```

Notice how Arithmetic Shift Right "duplicated" the top bit, where "logical shift right" brought in a zero.  It is *platform* specific on how this is actually interpreted, so try to stay away from it if possible, and stick to shifting unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = arg0 >> shift
```

This does a binary shift right of the contents of `arg0`. It does this shift `shift` number of times. So since `shift = 24`, it would shift `arg0` right 24 times.

```
temp = temp & 0x000000ff;
```

This masks the most significant bytes of what is contained in `temp`. The last byte remains, since anything `&`'ed with `f` just reflects the original value.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
temp = arg0 >> shift;
```

value of arg0 is shifted from most significant bits to lowest (be careful it could be left-to-right or right-to-left depend on endianness of the CPU) in value of shifts (first time 24 then 16 then 8)

```
temp = temp & 0x000000ff;
```

Binary AND applied to temp ie all except less significant 8 bits reset to 0, less significant 8 bits are not changed. If you need to implement that in assembly you may not need to do binary AND, but get proper byte instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = arg0 >> shift
```

This is a bit shift.  The integer value `arg0` will be shifted to the right by `shift` number of bits.

Example, if shift = 8 and arg0 = 0x1234 then temp will be assigned 0x12.

In your code if arg0 = 0x12345678 with shift = 24 then temp becomes 0x123456.

```
temp = temp & 0x000000ff;
```

This is a bitwise `and` operation.  The hex number 0x0000000ff is used to mask off the least significant byte before it is passed into byteToDec().

So in the last example where arg0 = 0x12345678, temp is shifted 24 to = 0x123456 then masked to 0x00000056.

As far as MIPS are concerned the  -- Shift Right Logical Variable (SRLV) instruction would be used for the shift

```
SRLV $d, $t, $s
```

Where $d is the destination register, $t the source register, and $s is the register holding the value of the number of shifts.  It's worth understanding that this shift introduces zeros from the left and will change the value of a signed integer that is negative, but since a mask is applied that applies zeros to all but the least significant byte it's ok and will save you some instructions.